# getting error from ajax call even though I know it has not errored

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am making an Ajax call.

I set a break-point in my c# code behind and I call it using ajax api query in jquery.

The c# code does not error but my error handler is being raised in the jquery/ajax code.

My script:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: "https://my cross domain/api/Login",
            data: LogIn,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divError").html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 >> callback comes here
                 $("#divError").html('Server Error');
            }
        });
```

it populates 'server error'in my div?

My code behind:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Login")]
public string Login([FromUri]Login login)
{
       >> setting break-point it gets to here
        return "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {              
        return "Server Error.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see the error raised in your handler? i.e 'errorThrown' ?

Comment: Hi, it just says 'error'. I thought maybe it could be because I was calling an https server from a http server. So ported the ip controller to the http and removed the crossover/cors and still get the same behaviour. Been on it all day and need sleep ! Thanks for your comment

Comment: What Ziv wanted to say is that you should print out the variable (for example errorThrown) not just 'Server Error' to see the error thrown.

Comment: Hi, yes I know that :) I was printing it out before and it just says 'error'

Comment: Maybe your server returns invalid json.

Comment: Yes, that had occurred to me so I changed the signature to return just a string but still get same error.

Comment: I may sound like I underestimate you again :) , but note that "" string is not valid json. Valid json would be "{}". I'm sorry I can't help.

Comment: I'd try replacing to empty json like @Andrej said, and for being sure I'd change the comment in your server from "Server Error" to Ex.Message, so that the string will be different between your server side and client side

Comment: @Andrej hi, a sorry for delay in response.  Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: @ZivWeissman Thanks, I shall try that now

Comment: /@ZivWeissman  the point you made about the 'server error'  ~ this line is never hit in my server and I do send myself teh true error anyway.  I had just simplified the c# code for the purpose of this question

Comment: @all I rebooted my server and it works without using the cross-domain. However, I really want to use the cross domain. i will post a separate question